# Modulo function for maxcompute

Tags: sql, alibaba-cloud

What’s the modulo function for maxcompute sql? I’ve been trying to use MOD but is getting an error. I’ve also searched but I can’t find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It’s not mod but just %. Can’t believe I searched 2hrs for this.